# How to add iPad and iPhone assets quickly?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I import an image, it gets placed in "Universal". Is there a way to tell xCode directly that that image is designed for iPad at @2x, and that image is designed for iPhone at @3x, and put those 2 together if they have the same name? Now I need to add everything manually, which takes a long time...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** further detail (cause I probably misread your question a little)...

Xcode should already be doing that for you... I just tried it:

- cat@2x.png
- cat@3x.png
- cat@2x~ipad.png

Select all three, drag and drop them into Assets in Xcode, and I automatically have a resource named "cat" with both 2x and 3x iPhone versions and a 2x iPad version.

[image]

Comment: They get placed in "Universal" like I said. Let's say your cat@2x is designed for Ipad, is there any way I can get 1 image set named "cat" and has 1 image in iPad folder (the cat@2x) and 1 image in iPhone folder (the cat@3x) without unclicking universal, checking ipad and iphone, and place the images accordingly? When adding alot of pictures, this is evil.

Comment: I think you *must* have the "~ipad" on the iPad image name to get it split out into iPhone + iPad versions.